# StringBuilder reverse changing my initial variable?

Tags: java, reference, stringbuilder, palindrome

I've recently started using Java, and I'm trying to get a short program that checks for palindromes in words or short sentences.
I want to use StringBuilder for the reverse method. My idea was to have one variable from the user entry (that is converted to lower case with spaces and commas removed) , and then another variable to hold the reversed entry, and compare them using .equals.
However, the .reverse() method is changing the value of my user entry, and I cannot figure out why. I know about references in Java, but only recently and don't have a full understanding.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Palindrome {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a word or phrase to test for a palindrome: ");
    String entry = kb.nextLine();

    String entryLower = entry.toLowerCase();
    String entryNoSpace = entryLower.replace(" ", "");
    String entryFinal = entryNoSpace.replace(",", "");

    //Convert String to StringBuilder to use reverse method
    StringBuilder sbEntry = new StringBuilder(entryFinal);
    System.out.println("sbEntry: " + sbEntry);

    StringBuilder sbEntryReverse = sbEntry.reverse();
    System.out.println("sbEntryReverse: " + sbEntryReverse);


    System.out.println("sbEntry: " + sbEntry);
```

For the word "Dog", this gives the output:

```
Enter a word or phrase to test for a palindrome: 
Dog
sbEntry: dog
sbEntryReverse: god
sbEntry: god
```

Comment: Have you read [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#reverse%28%29) for that method?

Comment: StringBuilder is mutable and when you perform operations on it, you alter it.

Comment: I had a look a the javadoc, but I still couldn't get it to work. GregTheRules has given me a working answer though in the replies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot compare `sbEntry` and `sbEntryReverse` because `sbEntry.reverse()` changes the contents of the `StringBuffer` to which `sbEntry` refers.  Unlike methods that operate on immutable `String` objects, `StringBuffer` methods like `reverse()` alter the character buffer inside the `StringBuffer` object.  `StringBuffer` objects are mutable while `String` objects are not.

Instead, you need to compare the final contents of the `StringBuffer` (`sbEntry` or `sbEntryReverse`) with the original input string, `entryFinal`:

```
String entryLower = entry.toLowerCase();
String entryNoSpace = entryLower.replace(" ", "");
String entryFinal = entryNoSpace.replace(",", "");

//Convert String to StringBuilder to use reverse method
StringBuilder sbEntry = new StringBuilder(entryFinal);
StringBuilder sbEntryReverse = sbEntry.reverse();
boolean isPalindrome = entryFinal.equals( sbEntryReverse.toString() );
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed description. It makes perfectly clear sense. I was not informed that StringBuffer objects are mutable whilst Strings aren't.

Comment: To avoid this mutability issue entirely, consider using `StringUtils.reverse(String)` or a similar method instead of `StringBuffer.reverse()`.  See http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#reverse(java.lang.String).

Comment: @DerekMahar So internally the `StringBuilder` maintains a copy of the `String` (or all `String`s appended) and when `reverse` is called that internal copy is modified?

Comment: @KevinBowersox Yes, only the internal copy is modified.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `reverse()` on a `StringBuilder` mutates (changes) its contents:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("hello");
System.out.println(sb); // hello

sb.reverse();
System.out.println(sb); // olleh

sb.reverse();
System.out.println(sb); // hello
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you pass a copy of the reference to sbEntry into the stringBuilder.

Instead of this :

```
StringBuilder sbEntryReverse = sbEntry.reverse();
```

Try this :

```
StringBuilder sbEntryReverse = new StringBuilder(sbEntry.toString()).reverse();
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked as I wanted it to. Can I just ask why adding .toString() does not affect the original variable?

Comment: Because toString() return a "valueOf" sbEntry without reference to the original variable.

Comment: Got it. My understanding of referencing is rough, but this has helped

Comment: There's no reason to create two `StringBuffer` objects.  Just create one to reverse the string and then compare that with the original input string (`entryFinal`).

Answer (score -1):

The Java doc says,

```
reverse()
Causes this character sequence to be replaced by the reverse of the sequence.
```

so it will replace your original String.

Comment: `reverse()` doesn't replace the original input string.  It replaces the contents of the character buffer internal to the `StringBuffer`.